# Can you render only part of a partial for a particular action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, partials

I have an item partial that has things like the item image, item price, and item description.  In the item partial I also have a small thumbnail of the user's avatar since it is a p2p marketplace.  I want this avatar rendered everywhere I `<%= render @items %>` except the users profile page (user controller, show action) where I'd like it left off because it's redundant.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  I've tried many things and am not even close.  Thanks for your help.

Here is the item partial code:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
          <%= link_to item_path(item) do %>
          <%= image_tag(item.image.url(:thumb)) %>
          <% end %>
      </div>

      <div class="caption">
        <% if item.user.avatar.url %>
          <%= link_to item.user do %>
            <%= image_tag(item.user.avatar.url(:thumb), class: "user-avatar-partial pull-left") %>
          <% end %>
        <% else %> 
          <%= link_to item.user do %>
            <%= image_tag 'avatar-thumb.png', class: "user-avatar-partial pull-left" %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
          <span id="item-name-partial"> 
            <%= link_to item_path(item) do %>
              <%= item.name.truncate(20) %>
            <% end %>
          </span>
            <span class="pull-right" id="item-price-partial"> 
              <%= link_to item_path(item) do %>
                <%= number_to_currency item.price %>
              <% end %>
            </span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solutions but in both of them you will have to modify the code a bit in your partial.

**Solution 1:**

Set an instance variable in the controller action and use that in your partial.

```
class UsersController
  def show
    @hide_small_thumbnail = true
    # rest of your code
  end
end
```

Then in your partial:

```
<% unless @hide_small_thumbnail %>
  <% #code for showing the thumbnail %>
<% end %>
```

Apart from that particular action, the value of the instance variable will be `nil` so your thumbnail will be displayed as is.

**Solution 2:**

Specify the controller and action name in your view. For example:

```
<% condition_one = (controller.controller_name == 'users') %>
<% condition_two = (controller.action_name == 'show') %>
<% unless condition_one && condition_two %>
  <% #code for showing the thumbnail %>
<% end %>
```

If I had to pick, I would go with the first one. But if you go with the latter, it would be better to move the conditions to a helper method and use the helper method, rather than the detailed conditions, in your view.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will try both and let everyone know what works (and accept answer if successful).

Comment: I went with the first solution and it worked like a charm.  Thanks a lot for providing the solution.